# solving rotation matrix angles using Gauss-Newton

Tags: numerical-methods, rotations, jacobian

I am attempting estimate the three angles of a rotation matrix that has been applied to a known set of vectors using the Gauss-Newton method through direct observation the rotated vectors that have been corrupted by noise. Given a set $\textrm{V}$ of $N$ known vectors

\begin{equation*}
\textrm{V} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 &  & x_N\\
y_1 & \cdots & y_N\\
z_1 & & z_N
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

with an applied rotation matrix $\textrm{R}$,
\begin{align*}\label{Rx}
\textrm{R}_{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos{\theta_{x}} & \sin{\theta_{x}}\\
0 & \sin{\theta_{x}} & \cos{\theta_{x}}
\end{bmatrix}
&
\textrm{R}_{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta_{y}} & 0 & -\sin{\theta_{y}}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\sin{\theta_{y}}  & 0 & \cos{\theta_{y}}
\end{bmatrix}
&
\textrm{R}_{z} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta_{z}} & -\sin{\theta_{z}} & 0\\
\sin{\theta_{z}} & \cos{\theta_{z}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{eqnarray*}\label{R}
\textrm{R} & = & \textrm{R}_z\textrm{R}_y\textrm{R}_x\\
  & = &
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta_y \cos\theta_z &  \cos\theta_z \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y - \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_z &  \cos\theta_x \cos\theta_z \sin\theta_y + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_z\\
 \cos\theta_y \sin\theta_z & \cos\theta_x \cos\theta_z + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z&  -\cos\theta_z \sin\theta_x + \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z \\
 -\sin\theta_y & \cos\theta_y \sin\theta_x & \cos\theta_x \cos\theta_y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

resulting rotated vectors $\textrm{W}$ are observed with noise $\eta$. 
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{W} = \textrm{R}\textrm{V} + \eta
\end{equation*}

Ideally, the $n^{th}$ column of $\textrm{W}$ is calculated as

\begin{equation*}\label{W}
 \textbf{w}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_n \cos\theta_y \cos\theta_z + 
 y_n ( \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y\cos\theta_z - \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_z) + 
 z_n (\cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y\cos\theta_z  + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_z)\\
 x_n \cos\theta_y \sin\theta_z + 
 y_n (\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_z + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z) + 
 z_n (-\sin\theta_x \cos\theta_z  + \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z) \\
 -x_n \sin\theta_y+
 y_n  \sin\theta_x \cos\theta_y+ 
 z_n \cos\theta_x \cos\theta_y  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Attempting to estimate the state vector $\beta$, the Jacobian is calculated as follows
\begin{equation*}
\beta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \theta_x \\ \theta_y \\ \theta_z
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\textrm{J}_n (\beta)= 
\begin{bmatrix}
j_{11} & j_{12} & j_{13}\\
j_{21} & j_{22} & j_{23}\\
j_{31} & j_{32} & j_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \textbf{w}_x}{\partial \theta_x} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_x}{\partial \theta_y} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_x}{\partial \theta_z}\\
\frac{\partial \textbf{w}_y}{\partial \theta_x} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_y}{\partial \theta_y} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_y}{\partial \theta_z}\\
\frac{\partial \textbf{w}_z}{\partial \theta_x} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_z}{\partial \theta_y} & \frac{\partial \textbf{w}_z}{\partial \theta_z}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
j_{11} & = &  y_n (\cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \cos\theta_z + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_z) + z_n (-\sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \cos\theta_z + \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_z)\\
j_{12} & = & - 
x_n \sin\theta_y \cos\theta_z + y_n \sin\theta_x\cos\theta_y \cos\theta_z + z_n\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_y \cos\theta_z   \\
j_{13}& = &-x_n\cos\theta_y \sin\theta_z +
y_n(- \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z-\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_z ) + z_n( - \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z+\sin\theta_x \cos\theta_z) \\
j_{21} & = &y_n(-\sin\theta_x \cos\theta_z + \cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z) + 
 z_n(-\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_z - \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z)\\
j_{22} & = & -x_n\sin\theta_y \sin\theta_z + y_n\sin\theta_x\cos\theta_y \sin\theta_z +z_n\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_y \sin\theta_z \\
j_{23} & = & x_n\cos\theta_y \cos\theta_z + y_n(-\cos\theta_x \sin\theta_z + \sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y \cos\theta_z ) + z_n(\sin\theta_x \sin\theta_z + \cos\theta_x\sin\theta_y \cos\theta_z)\\
j_{31} & = & y_n\cos\theta_x \cos\theta_y - z_n \sin\theta_x\cos\theta_y\\
j_{32} & = & -x_n\cos\theta_y - y_n\sin\theta_x \sin\theta_y - z_n\cos\theta_x \sin\theta_y \\
j_{33} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Residuals $\textbf{r}$ are defined as 
\begin{equation*}
 \textbf{r} = \textrm{W} - \textrm{V} = \begin{bmatrix}
 r_{1,1} & \cdots & r_{1,N}\\
 r_{2,1} & \cdots & r_{2,N}\\
 r_{3,1} & \cdots & r_{3,N}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Updating $\beta$ using the Gauss-Newton method is then implemented as follows 
\begin{align*}
\underset{3N\times 3}{\textrm{J}(\beta)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textrm{J}_1({\beta})\\
\vdots\\
\textrm{J}_N({\beta})
\end{bmatrix}
& \ &
\underset{3N\times 1}{\textbf{r}}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{1,1}\\
r_{2,1}\\
r_{3,1}\\
\vdots\\
r_{1,N}\\
r_{2,N}\\
r_{3,N}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
 \beta_k = \beta_{k-1} - \left(\textrm{J}^T\textrm{J} \right)^{-1}\textrm{J}^T\textbf{r}
\end{equation*}

This procedure does not yield the correct solution. Is there a reason the Gauss Newton method does not work in this situation? I am pretty sure the Jacobian is correct since it was computed in Mathematica and then verified by hand. Is there something I am overlooking here?